# How to write in firebase database from another project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

There are 2 projects, one project is about a restaurant internal order management and the other is a food platform with multiple restaurants.

I want write into the database of the restaurant from the food ordering app without connecting my app to the restaurant project.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find a way to do this automatically without connecting them. a workaround could be to export the data and reimport it into the other project. in theory, you could even make a script do this for you.

Comment: that being said, I could be wrong, I would love to know about another way to do it if there is one